# Richfaces Resource Optimization settings in RF 4.0.0-Final

Tags: optimization, compression, richfaces, pack

I'm attempting to turn on resource optimization (packing) for my applicaiton using RF 4.0.0 running under JBoss 6.1.0

I know that the means to turn this on changed from RF 3.x to RF 4.x (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Upgrading)

The problem is neither the 3.x means or the 4.x means seem to work with the 4.0.0-Final version.

I'm also using skinning (blueSky) and have seen posts that indicate that packing doesn't work with a skinned application.

In my web.xml I've inserted both sets of configuration parameters, but the app refuses to pack and compress all of the RF .js and .css files

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the answer ... for RF 4.0.0.Final version there is no support for either set of optimization settings.

Here's a relevant post:
https://community.jboss.org/message/605001

To solve the problem I've upgraded to the latest (as of this date) 4.X version which is 4.3.4.

If someone can answer this to the contrary let me know.

As an aside, the only compatability issues I've found so far going from 4.0.0.Final to 4.3.4.Final are:
- I needed to add switchType="client" to some rich:accordian components that did not specify a switch type.
I still need to do more testing